# Objective-C: Setting an alpha value with an array of elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm quite new at objective-c and I'm trying to set an array of labels at 0.0 Alpha with a for loop. Can someone give me a help?

```
 NSArray *fadeLabels = @[@"_lonLabel", @"_firstLat",@"_firstLon",@"_firstReal",@"_firstMagnetic",@"_firstSpeed",@"_speedLabel",@"_realNorthLabel",@"_magneticNorthLabel"];

    for (int i=0; i<[fadeLabels count]; i++) {
        [fadeLabels objectAtIndex:i];
        //setAlpha:0.0f?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of views instead of array of strings. insert you views in the array.

```
NSArray *fadeLabels = @[ _lonLabel, _firstLat, _firstLon, _firstReal, _firstMagnetic, _firstSpeed, _speedLabel, _realNorthLabel, _magneticNorthLabel];

for (int i=0; i<[fadeLabels count]; i++) {
    UIView *view = (UIView *)[fadeLabels objectAtIndex:i];
    [view setAlpha:0.0f];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are assigning array with the `String` with name is `equalTo` your `UILabel` object so you need to

replace your array elements like this

`@"_lonLabel"` to `_lonLabel`

```
 NSArray *fadeLabels = @[ _lonLabel, _firstLat, _firstLon, _firstReal, _firstMagnetic, _firstSpeed, _speedLabel, _realNorthLabel, _magneticNorthLabel];

    for (int i=0; i<[fadeLabels count]; i++) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)fadeLabels[i];
        label.alpha = 0.0;

    }
```

Comment: you have syntax

Comment: true, if all views are all labels. but, the concept is the same.

Comment: @FuManchu You enjoy buddy. need help you can ask (y)

Answer (score 1):

You also should better use `for...in` instead of the "old" `for`.

```
NSArray *fadeLabels = @[ _lonLabel, _firstLat, _firstLon, _firstReal, _firstMagnetic, _firstSpeed, _speedLabel, _realNorthLabel, _magneticNorthLabel];

for (UILabel *label in fadeLabels) {
    label.alpha = 0.0;
}
```